# Open a view in specific postion in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I use the following code to open a view in Eclipse workbench based application:

```java
HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(paramExecutionEvent).getActivePage().showView("viewId");
```

This view which I am opening is defined in an external plugin and I don't have control on its source. I just open the view by knowing the view-id.

The current perspective has one main active view on top, and three views open below the main view arranged next to each other.

By default it opens next to the main top view, thereby hiding the main view. But I want to open this specific view below the main view along with the three secondary views, so that the main top view is still visible.

I do not have access to source of any of these views or the perspective definition in plugin.xml. I am opening this view by having a custom menu in my plugin.

Kindly help in achieve this. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension point in your plug-in to add a definition for the view position in a perspective. Use the `view` element to position a view.

For example:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions"> 
    <perspectiveExtension 
        targetID="org.eclipse.ui.resourcePerspective"> 
        <view id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.TypeHierarchy" 
            relative="org.eclipse.ui.views.ResourceNavigator" 
            relationship="left" 
            ratio="0.50"/> 
    </perspectiveExtension> 
</extension>
```

This is adding to the `org.eclipse.ui.resourcePerspective` perspective. It defines the position of the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.TypeHierarchy` relative to the `org.eclipse.ui.views.ResourceNavigator` view.

Comment: wow, wonderful quick answer. I would try it straightaway and mark it as accepted. i need to find out the relationship value to specify to place it below another view. Thanks!